# Google Oauth requires domain (not available) for user type EXTERNAL

Tags: oauth, gmail

I have an excel workbook using VBA to send individual gmails to multiple “google group” members. It had been working for 4 years until Gmail added Oauth.
I feed the member and email body from an excel spreadsheet.
*5/23/2022 18:51    |Garrett | email@yahoo.com |    Challenge, June 2 @ 9:36, Pine Hollow, June 6 @ 8:30, Mill Creek, June 9 @ 8:30, Stoney Creek, June 13 @ 8:30, Bryan Park, June 16 @ 9:00—Pick your foursome, Chapel Ridge, June 27 @ 8:40*

I can test the app in test mode and it will send the email if I manually authorize and add include read. Compose, send and delete   permissions. When I configure it as production, I get not verified message and go through a similar routine that test needed.

Currently the file is on my local disk. I run this from my google account xxxx@gmail,com and my google account has owner permissions for gmail. I only want to send emails not read, compose or delete

Now my problem is: when I request Oauth verification, my user type is external (required) and it requires a domain URL which I don’t have.
What can I do to bypass the Domain requirement or am I approaching this incorrectly?